# php searching in more than one column mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to make a code to search for data in more than one column , the code works only if I search in one column. when I tried to search in two columns it says that nothing is found in the database.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="param" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"> 
</form>

if (isset($_POST['param'])) {
$param= trim ($_POST['param']);

$result = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE student_Name LIKE '%$param%' AND course_name LIKE '%$param%'";
```

Comment: I think you want to try `OR` instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `OR` unless you want to check the 2 columns with the same parameter.

`$result = "SELECT * FROM thecars WHERE student_Name LIKE '%$param%' OR course_name LIKE '%$param%'";`

Also, this is very open to SQL injection. Sanitize your input before you pass it to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a concat and search via that.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM thecars WHERE CONCAT(`student_Name`, `course_name`) AS `search`LIKE '%$param%'";
```

Comment: I havent tested this out by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Your using the same `$param` variable to search on both columns. If your searching for 2 separate values provide a form that supports inputting 2 values. And then handle such input properly in your query formation.

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="param1" >
<input type="text" name="param2" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"> 
</form>

if (isset($_POST['param1']) || isset($_POST['param2'])) {
$param1 = trim ($_POST['param1']);
$param2 = trim ($_POST['param2']);

$result = "SELECT * FROM thecars WHERE student_Name LIKE '%$param1%' AND course_name LIKE '%$param2%'";
```

Also change your column aggregation in where clause to `OR` as suggested by others if your searching for similar outcome.